# Validate the path of a url in PHP

Tags: php, regex, url, path

In PHP, I'm trying to validate the path of an Url with regex.
The current regex that I have tested is this one:
`^(\/\w+)+\.\w+(\?(\w+=[\w\d]+(&\w+=[\w\d]+)+)+)*$`

```
public function isValidPath($urlPath)
{
    if (!preg_match("#^(\/\w+)+\.\w+(\?(\w+=[\w\d]+(&\w+=[\w\d]+)+)+)*$#i", $urlPath)) { return false; }
    else { return true; }         
}

$arrUrl = parse_url($url);
$urlPath = $arrUrl['path'];
// valid path ?
if(isValidPath($urlPath)) { echo "OK"; }
else { echo "Invalid Path URL"; }
```

But it doesn't work with path that just start with `/`.

```
 - / -> valid path
 - /aaa -> valid path
 - /aaa/bbb -> valid path
 - /aaa?q=x -> valid path
 - aaa -> Not valid path
 - /asd/asd./jsp -> Not valid path
 - /asd/asd.jsp/  -> Not valid path
 - /asd./asd.jsp -> Not valid path
 - /asd///asd.js -> Not valid path
 - /asd/asd.jsp&bar=baz?inga=42?quux -> Not valid path
```

I'm not a regex expert and I'm breaking my head trying to do one that seems very simple.

Comment: are you looking to see if a file/page actually exists at the url provided ?

Comment: `filter_var('http://nothing.com' . $urlPath, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` will validate the url

Comment: @cmorrissey `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` doesn't work with this example `http://somesite.com/asd/asd.jsp&bar=baz?inga=42?quux` - https://ideone.com/BRHXpU

Comment: @PedroLobito thats because its not valid, the get string should be `?bar=baz&inga=42&quux`

Comment: Of course it's not valid, but  `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`  says it is... did you check the ideone link ?

Comment: @cmorrissey,  I have millions of Urls to tested. I can't ask the server to check all Urls.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
^\/(?!.*\/$)(?!.*[\/]{2,})(?!.*\?.*\?)(?!.*\.\/).*
```

Sample function:

```
function validateUrl($url){
if (preg_match('%^/(?!.*\/$)(?!.*[\/]{2,})(?!.*\?.*\?)(?!.*\.\/).*%im', $url)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

I've used some negative [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that exclude certain patterns.
Its matches only the "valid paths" you specified.

[Regex101Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qD2sV5/1)

Comment: Pedro, thanks for you help. 
But I want to validate all path, not  only example "valid paths" I'm specified.

For ex. with you regex this path `/'+$(abc.abcd[zz].wxyz).azerty(` is OK. But isn't.

Comment: I understand your point, you can try to extend the regex with a couple more look-aheads.

Answer (score 0):

I use @cmorrissey's approach, which actually does not require regex:

```
$result = filter_var('http://www.example.com' . $path, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);

if ($result !== false) {
    $result = true;
}
```

`result` is then `true` or `false` depending on path validity. Note that paths should always start with a `/` else they are *part of a path* rather than a complete path.